# Let X and Y be independent and identically distributed random variables with probability density function. Then P(y<x<2)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X and Y be independent and identically distributed random variables with probability density function

f(x)= \begin{cases}
       e^{-x}  & x>0\\
        0 & otherwise\\
    \end{cases}
Then P(y<x<2)  = 
My attempt at the solution:\begin{align}
p(y<x<2)=p(x<2)p(y<2)-p(y \geq x) 
=\int_{0}^{2}e^{-x}dx\int_{0}^{2}e^{-y}dy -\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{y}e^{-x}dx dy
\end{align}
But doing this is not giving me the correct answer. Can somebody please tell me where I am going wrong and give me the correct approach

Comment: It looks like you're missing an $e^{-y}$ in the last integral.

Comment: Also, notice that the last term is $P(X\le Y\le 2)$, not $P(X\le Y)$. And $P(X=Y)=0$, so there's a helpful symmetry to the problem since X and Y are independent and identically distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these types of problems it is always helpful to draw pictures. First, we have for the joint density of $X$ and $Y$:
$$
f_{XY}(x,y)=e^{-x}e^{-y},\quad 0<x,y<\infty.
$$
Now draw the region $0<y<x<2$:

[image]

The probability in question can now easily be written as an integral in the form
$$
\mathsf P(Y<X<2)=\int_0^2\int_0^x e^{-x}e^{-y}\,\mathrm dy\mathrm dx=\frac{\left(e^2-1\right)^2}{2 e^4}\approx 0.75.
$$